# Cell colors in a GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I'm using a CellTable and would like to programatically change the background color of certain cells in some situations. I tried it with an Custom Cell as described in the documentation and changed the background color with

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant ("<div style=\"background-color:blue;\">");
sb.append (safeValue);
sb.appendHtmlConstant ("</div>");
```

This basically works, but seems to be quite slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can Override `getCellStyleNames()` and return the wanted style for the cell

```
            TextColumn<Composant> nameColumn= new TextColumn<Composant>() {

                @Override
               public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, Composant  object) {
                     return "styleName";
                 }  

                @Override
                public String  getValue(Composant object) {                                         
                    return object.getName();
                }           

              };
```

Comment: It's important that you can do this just with GWT > 2.4